# how to sort an array of object by the element value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have an array of objects which is shown below

```
 [
  0: {name: "CMT", priority: 2}
  1: {name: "CDR BILLING", priority: 1}
  2: {name: "POOL DATA", priority: 5}
  3: {name: "FFM", priority: 3}
  4: {name: "SMPP", priority: 6}
  5: {name: "OTC", priority: 4}
 ];
```

how to sort this array such that the elemet having priority 1 shoould be at 0 index.What i want to achieve is

```
  [
  0: {name: "CDR BILLING", priority: 1}
  1: {name: "CMT", priority: 2}
  2: {name: "FFM", priority: 3} .....and so on
  ];
```

Comment: `let sorted = myArray.sort((a,b) => a.priority - b.priority)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

```js
let list = [
 {name: "CMT", priority: 2},
 {name: "CDR BILLING", priority: 1},
 {name: "POOL DATA", priority: 5},
 {name: "FFM", priority: 3},
 {name: "SMPP", priority: 6},
 {name: "OTC", priority: 4}
 ];
 
let listCopy = [...list];
listCopy.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.priority - b.priority;
});

console.log(listCopy);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[
   {name: "CMT", priority: 2},
   {name: "CDR BILLING", priority: 1},
   {name: "POOL DATA", priority: 5},
   {name: "FFM", priority: 3},
   {name: "SMPP", priority: 6},
   {name: "OTC", priority: 4}
 ].sort((a,b)=>a.priority-b.priority) //! edited
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I tested it in chrome. the function inside `.sort` should return a number -- see Saurabh's answer above.

Comment: youre right, it should return number. I will correct the answer. Anyway, funny thing: I tested it on firefox before, and it is worked ok.

Comment: that's interesting, it works on firefox for me as well. I suspect the reasoning for that is that the javascript spec does not define what happens when the callback returns something other than a number, and firefox has chosen to implement sorting in that case as well. It's still technically within spec.

Comment: and  that tricked me, anyway thanks for pointing it out :)